# Wrap value into range [min,max] without division

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there any way in C# to wrap a given value x between x_min and x_max. The value should not be clamped as in `Math.Min/Max` but wrapped like a `float` modulus.

A way to implement this would be:

```
x = x - (x_max - x_min) * floor( x / (x_max - x_min));
```

However, I am wondering if there is an algorithm or C# method that implements the same functionality without divisions and without the likely float-limited-precision issues that may arise when the value lies far away from the desired range.

Comment: What do you mean between two number, you could just use an if statement

Comment: What is the purpose of doint that?

Comment: What's the purpose of this formula?  If you want to keep x between two values, wouldn't this do the job?  `Math.Min(Math.Max(x_min, x), x_max)` I doubt that involves floating point division.

Comment: The above formula implements wrapping and not clamping. Math.Min/Max would simply cut off values which I do not want. Think of wrapping angles between 0 and 2pi but the above is more general.

Comment: By the way, could anyone explain why the question is voted down? To me it seems to fit nicely to the concept of StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: I haven't voted it down, but tt doesn't fit well with StackOverflow in its current state because you have yet to really explain your problem or what you are trying to do. I added a "non-clamping" division-less answer below, but now I realize you seem to be concerned with precision and not performance.  Could you please _explain_ what your formula is actually doing beyond that it's "wrapping", because I think everyone here, including myself, has yet to really understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JLRishe: They want to do the equivalent of a modulus but instead of wrapping at < 0 and > n they want to wrap at < n1 and > n2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can wrap it using two modulo operations, **which is still equivalent to a division**. I don't think there is a more efficient way of doing this without assuming something about `x`.

```
x = (((x - x_min) % (x_max - x_min)) + (x_max - x_min)) % (x_max - x_min) + x_min;
```

The additional sum and modulo in the formula are to handle those cases where `x` is actually less than `x_min` and the modulo might come up negative. Or you could do this with an `if`, and a single modular division:

```
if (x < x_min)
    x = x_max - (x_min - x) % (x_max - x_min);
else
    x = x_min + (x - x_min) % (x_max - x_min);
```

Unless `x` is not far from `x_min` and `x_max`, and is reachable with very few sums or subtractions (think also *error propagation*), I think the modulo is your only available method.

## Without division

Keeping in mind that error propagation might become relevant, we can do this with a cycle:

```
d = x_max - x_min;
if (abs(d) < MINIMUM_PRECISION) {
    return x_min; // Actually a divide by zero error :-)
}
while (x < x_min) {
    x += d;
}
while (x > x_max) {
    x -= d;
}
```

## Note on probabilities

The use of modular arithmetic has some statistical implications (floating point arithmetic also would have different ones).

For example say we wrap a random value between 0 and 5 included (e.g. a six-sided dice result) into a [0,1] range (i.e. a coin flip). Then

```
0 -> 0      1 -> 1
2 -> 0      3 -> 1
4 -> 0      5 -> 1
```

if the input has flat spectrum, i.e., every number (0-5) has 1/6 probability, the output will also be flat, and each item will have 3/6 = 50% probability.

But if we had a five-sided dice (0-4), or if we had a random number between 0 and 32767 and wanted to reduce it in the (0, 99) range to get a percentage, the output would not be flat, and some number would be slightly (or not so slightly) more likely than others. In the five-sided dice to coin-flip case, heads vs. tails would be 60%-40%. In the 32767-to-percent case, percentages below 67 would be CEIL(32767/100)/FLOOR(32767/100) = 0.3% more likely to come up than the others.

(To see this more clearly, consider the number to be from "00000" to "32767": once every 328 throws, the first three digits of the number will be "327". When this happens, the last two digits can only go from "00" to "67", they cannot be "68" to "99" because 32768 is out of range. So, digits from 00 to 67 are slightly more likely.

So, if one wanted a flat output, one would have to ensure that (max-min) was a divisor of the input range. In the case of 32767 and 100, the input range would have to be truncated at the nearest hundred (minus one), 32699, so that (0-32699) contained 32700 outcomes. Whenever the input was >= 32700, the input function would have to be called again to obtain a new value:

```
function reduced() {
#ifdef RECURSIVE
    int x = get_random();
    if (x > MAX_ALLOWED) {
        return reduced(); // Retry
    }
#else
    for (;;) {
        int x = get_random();
        int d = x_max - x_min;
        if (x > MAX_ALLOWED) {
            continue; // Retry
        }
    }
#endif
    return x_min + (
             (
               (x - x_min) % d
             ) + d
           ) % d;
```

When (INPUTRANGE%OUTPUTRANGE)/(INPUTRANGE) is significant, the overhead might be considerable (e.g. reducing 0-197 to 0-99 requires making roughly twice as many calls).

If the input range is less than the output range (e.g. we have a coin flipper and we want to make a dice tosser), multiply (do not add) using Horner's algorithm as many times as required to get an input range which is larger. Coin flip has a range of 2, CEIL(LN(OUTPUTRANGE)/LN(INPUTRANGE)) is 3, so we need three multiplications:

```
for (;;) {
    x = ( flip() * 2 + flip() ) * 2 + flip();
    if (x < 6) {
        break;
    }
}
```

or to get a number between 122 and 221 (range=100) out of a dice tosser:

```
for (;;) {
    // ROUNDS = 1 + FLOOR(LN(OUTPUTRANGE)/LN(INPUTRANGE)) and can be hardwired
    // INPUTRANGE is 6
    // x = 0; for (i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++) { x = 6*x + dice();  }
    x = dice() + 6 * ( 
            dice() + 6 * ( 
                dice() /* + 6*... */
            )
        );
    if (x < 200) {
        break;
    }
}
// x is now 0..199, x/2 is 0..99
y = 122 + x/2;
```

Answer (score 11):

Modulo works fine on floating point, so how about:

```
x = ((x-x_min) % (x_max - x_min) ) + x_min;
```

It's still effectively a divide though, and you need to tweak it for values less < min...

You are worrying about accuracy when the number is far away from the range. However this is not related to the modulo operation, however it is performed, but is a property of floating point. If you take a number between 0 and 1, and you add a large constant to it, say to bring it into the range 100 to 101, it will lose some precision.

Answer (score 1):

Are min and max fixed values? If so, you could figure out their range and the inverse of that in advance:

```
const decimal x_min = 5.6m;
const decimal x_max = 8.9m;
const decimal x_range = x_max - x_min;
const decimal x_range_inv = 1 / x_range;

public static decimal WrapValue(decimal x)
{
    return x - x_range * floor(x * x_range_inv);
}
```

The multiplication should perform somewhat better than division.

Comment: I'd test that extensively, both performance-wise and precision-wise; you have two multiplications and a conversion in there. If the range is small, and x is very near the beginning of the range, I think you might experience problems. Actually, it would be good to have a couple of test cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = x<x_min?  x_min:
    x>x_max?  x_max:x;
```

Its a little convoluted, and you can definitely break it into a pair of if statements.. But I don't see the need for division to begin with.

Edit:

I seem to have missunderstood, le

```
x = x<x_min?  x_max - (x_min - x):
    x>x_max?  x_min + (x - x_max):x;
```

This would work if your value of x does not vary too much.. which might work depending on the use case. Else for a more robust version I expect you need divide or repeated (recursive?) subtraction atleast.

This should be a more robust version which keeps performing the above calculation until x is stable.

```
int x = ?, oldx = x+1; // random init value.

while(x != oldx){
    oldx = x;
    x = x<x_min?  x_max - (x_min - x):
        x>x_max?  x_min + (x - x_max):x;
}
```

Comment: That seems more like a clamp, rather than 'wrapping'.

Comment: @JasonD ah yes, didnt see his last statement

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to clamp but wrap (also, I improved my question).

Answer (score 0):

How about using an extension method on `IComparable`.

```
public static class LimitExtension
{
    public static T Limit<T>(this T value, T min, T max)
         where T : IComparable
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(min) < 0) return min;
        if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0) return max;

        return value;
    }
}
```

And a unit test:

```
public class LimitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        int number = 3;

        Assert.Equal(3, number.Limit(0, 4));
        Assert.Equal(4, number.Limit(4, 6));
        Assert.Equal(1, number.Limit(0, 1));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do not want to clamp but wrap (see improved question).

Answer (score 0):

LinqPad SAMPLE CODE (Restricted to 3 decimal places)

```
void Main()
{ 
    Test(int.MinValue, 0, 1,0.1f, "value = int.MinValue");
    Test(int.MinValue, -2,- 1,0.1f, "value = int.MinValue");
    Test(int.MaxValue, 0, 1,0.1f, "value = int.MaxValue");
    Test(int.MaxValue, -2,- 1,0.1f, "value = int.MaxValue");
    Test(-2,-2,-1,0.1f, string.Empty);
    Test(0,0,1,0.1f, string.Empty);
    Test(1,1,2,0.1f, string.Empty);

    Test(int.MinValue, 0, 1, -0.1f, "value = int.MinValue");
    Test(int.MinValue, -2,- 1, -0.1f, "value = int.MinValue");
    Test(int.MaxValue, 0, 1, -0.1f, "value = int.MaxValue");
    Test(int.MaxValue, -2,- 1, -0.1f, "value = int.MaxValue");
    Test(-2,-2,-1, -0.1f, string.Empty);
    Test(0,0,1, -0.1f, string.Empty);
    Test(1,1,2, -0.1f, string.Empty);
}

private void Test(float value, float min ,float max, float direction, string comment)
{
    "".Dump("    " + min + " to " + max + " direction = " + direction + "   " + comment);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        value = (float)Math.Round(min + ((value - min) % (max - min)), 3); 
        string.Format("    {1} -> value: {0}", value,  i).Dump(); 
        value = value + direction < min && direction < 0 ? max + direction : value + direction;
    }
}
```

RESULTS

```
0 to 1 direction = 0.1   value = int.MinValue

0 -> value: 0
1 -> value: 0.1
2 -> value: 0.2
3 -> value: 0.3
4 -> value: 0.4
5 -> value: 0.5
6 -> value: 0.6
7 -> value: 0.7
8 -> value: 0.8
9 -> value: 0.9
10 -> value: 0

-2 to -1 direction = 0.1   value = int.MinValue

0 -> value: -2
1 -> value: -1.9
2 -> value: -1.8
3 -> value: -1.7
4 -> value: -1.6
5 -> value: -1.5
6 -> value: -1.4
7 -> value: -1.3
8 -> value: -1.2
9 -> value: -1.1
10 -> value: -2

0 to 1 direction = 0.1   value = int.MaxValue

0 -> value: 0
1 -> value: 0.1
2 -> value: 0.2
3 -> value: 0.3
4 -> value: 0.4
5 -> value: 0.5
6 -> value: 0.6
7 -> value: 0.7
8 -> value: 0.8
9 -> value: 0.9
10 -> value: 0

-2 to -1 direction = 0.1   value = int.MaxValue

0 -> value: -2
1 -> value: -1.9
2 -> value: -1.8
3 -> value: -1.7
4 -> value: -1.6
5 -> value: -1.5
6 -> value: -1.4
7 -> value: -1.3
8 -> value: -1.2
9 -> value: -1.1
10 -> value: -2

-2 to -1 direction = 0.1   

0 -> value: -2
1 -> value: -1.9
2 -> value: -1.8
3 -> value: -1.7
4 -> value: -1.6
5 -> value: -1.5
6 -> value: -1.4
7 -> value: -1.3
8 -> value: -1.2
9 -> value: -1.1
10 -> value: -2

0 to 1 direction = 0.1   

0 -> value: 0
1 -> value: 0.1
2 -> value: 0.2
3 -> value: 0.3
4 -> value: 0.4
5 -> value: 0.5
6 -> value: 0.6
7 -> value: 0.7
8 -> value: 0.8
9 -> value: 0.9
10 -> value: 0

1 to 2 direction = 0.1   

0 -> value: 1
1 -> value: 1.1
2 -> value: 1.2
3 -> value: 1.3
4 -> value: 1.4
5 -> value: 1.5
6 -> value: 1.6
7 -> value: 1.7
8 -> value: 1.8
9 -> value: 1.9
10 -> value: 1

0 to 1 direction = -0.1   value = int.MinValue

0 -> value: 0
1 -> value: 0.9
2 -> value: 0.8
3 -> value: 0.7
4 -> value: 0.6
5 -> value: 0.5
6 -> value: 0.4
7 -> value: 0.3
8 -> value: 0.2
9 -> value: 0.1
10 -> value: 0

-2 to -1 direction = -0.1   value = int.MinValue

0 -> value: -2
1 -> value: -1.1
2 -> value: -1.2
3 -> value: -1.3
4 -> value: -1.4
5 -> value: -1.5
6 -> value: -1.6
7 -> value: -1.7
8 -> value: -1.8
9 -> value: -1.9
10 -> value: -2

0 to 1 direction = -0.1   value = int.MaxValue

0 -> value: 0
1 -> value: 0.9
2 -> value: 0.8
3 -> value: 0.7
4 -> value: 0.6
5 -> value: 0.5
6 -> value: 0.4
7 -> value: 0.3
8 -> value: 0.2
9 -> value: 0.1
10 -> value: 0

-2 to -1 direction = -0.1   value = int.MaxValue

0 -> value: -2
1 -> value: -1.1
2 -> value: -1.2
3 -> value: -1.3
4 -> value: -1.4
5 -> value: -1.5
6 -> value: -1.6
7 -> value: -1.7
8 -> value: -1.8
9 -> value: -1.9
10 -> value: -2

-2 to -1 direction = -0.1   

0 -> value: -2
1 -> value: -1.1
2 -> value: -1.2
3 -> value: -1.3
4 -> value: -1.4
5 -> value: -1.5
6 -> value: -1.6
7 -> value: -1.7
8 -> value: -1.8
9 -> value: -1.9
10 -> value: -2

0 to 1 direction = -0.1   

0 -> value: 0
1 -> value: 0.9
2 -> value: 0.8
3 -> value: 0.7
4 -> value: 0.6
5 -> value: 0.5
6 -> value: 0.4
7 -> value: 0.3
8 -> value: 0.2
9 -> value: 0.1
10 -> value: 0

1 to 2 direction = -0.1   

0 -> value: 1
1 -> value: 1.9
2 -> value: 1.8
3 -> value: 1.7
4 -> value: 1.6
5 -> value: 1.5
6 -> value: 1.4
7 -> value: 1.3
8 -> value: 1.2
9 -> value: 1.1
10 -> value: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to add the constraint of a min value of 0, simplifying LSerni's answer above is: `x = ((x % x_max) + x_max) % x_max`

The first `x % x_max` operation will always be negative when `x` is less than the 0 min value. This allows the second modulus operation of that simplification to be replaced with a less than 0 comparison.

```
float wrap0MinValue(float x, float x_max)
{
    int result = toWrap % maxValue;
    if (result < 0) // set negative result back into positive range
        result = maxValue + result;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For the very specific case of range 0..1 this seems to work:

```
float wrap(float n) {
    if (n > 1.0) {
        return n - floor(n);
    }
    if (n < 0.0) {
        return n + ceil(abs(n));
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

use [Wouter de Kort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14415832/1991068)'s answer but change

```
if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0) return max;
```

to

```
if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0) return min;
```

Comment: That will not work. If the range is 0-5 for instance, then 7 should give 1, 8 should give 2 etc. This code would produce 0 for any number greater than 5 in that scenario.

Comment: This is a clamp; not a wrap. OP wants a wrap between +/-180 or 0...360, etc.